# Regex for uppercase, numbers and symbols mix and match

Tags: regex

Trying to come up with the proper Regex for Uppercase, Numbers and Symbols (-,'.) in various order.

It would be ok to have this:
ABC.NO
555.COM
COM BLALBA
BLABLABLA
555
DON'T

But not this:
abc.no
555.coM
com blAbla
DON't

Actually it doesn't matter what you use, as long as the letters are capitals.
I got this so far : [A-Z0-9\W ] but it's clearly not enough according to this:
http://www.rubular.com/r/HLtrfifMbZ

Comment: Do you mean you want to match a string that does not contain lowercase letters? Try `^[^a-z]+$`.

Comment: That's exactly it!!

Comment: The answer has been sniped anyway. BTW, you can't use `^` and `$` to test string boundaries in Ruby, you need `\A` and `\z`.

Comment: Is it for Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either search for what you DO want with something like:

```
/^[A-Z \t.\d']+$/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WcDERz/1/)

Or specify what you DON"T want with:

```
/^[^a-z]+$/
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/2Z5P2y/2/)

Which one to use is dependent on what you are trying to select or reject.